# How to use preg_replace to replace one duplicated substring per iteration?

Tags: php, loops, preg-replace

I have a string like this:

```
$replace = "I am a [[boy]], he is a[[boy]] too."
```

What I want to do is to replace the first `[[boy]]` with the word "Blank1" and the second `[[boy]]` with "Blank2".

What I have tried:

```
for($i=1;$i<=count($questions[$qn_count]['correct_ans']);$i++){     
    $word = "##BLK".$i."##";                
    $pattern_bracket = "/\[\[([^\]]+)\]\]/";            
    $ff = preg_replace($pattern_bracket,$word , $replace, $i);          
}
$questions[$qn_count]['body'] = $ff;
```

The above `[[ ]]` will always appeared to be the same replacement with ##BLK2##.
Is it possible for me to replace the two brackets will different value?

Comment: Why regex if it's static words?

Comment: I think it is the same, as [[boy]] also appear twice.

Comment: A simple str_replace would suffice If it's only static word as @Andreas mentioned. If not, could you add what's in the $pattern_bracket variable ?

Comment: If i put  $ff = preg_replace("[[boy]]", $word, $replace, $i);  the two results will also be replaced by $word = "##BLK" . $i . "##"

Comment: why are you limiting the number of replacement to `$i`? it means that `##BLK1##` will replace one time max, `##BLK2##` two times, etc. Is it what's intended?

Comment: I use the wrong method. As I want to replace the two [[boy]] with different values, but it's not work

Comment: Try to store result of preg_replace function in $replace variable instead of $ff. And use constant "1" in 4th parameter of preg_replace() if You want to replace one placeholder in each iteration.

Comment: if you want to replace one element at a time, you should use `preg_replace($pattern_bracket,$word , $replace, 1);` (1 instead of $i). And as stated by A.Mikhailov, if each loop turn doesn't store the result in `$replace`, each loop turn will forget what the previous one did

Comment: it's work!! Thx for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little fuzzy on the details, but I think this is the general method that you are looking for:

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/921de477e58f40191e5b51424eeefc9980fe0aa2))

```
$string="I am a [[boy]], he is a[[boy]] too.";
$swaps=['Blank1','Blank2'];
echo "$string\n";
foreach($swaps as $swap){
    $string=preg_replace('/\[{2}[^]]+\]{2}/',$swap,$string,1);
    echo "$string\n";
}
```

Output:

```
I am a [[boy]], he is a[[boy]] too.
I am a Blank1, he is a[[boy]] too.
I am a Blank1, he is aBlank2 too.
```

Just a couple of notes:

- You don't need to escape the square bracket in your negated character class.
- Using curly bracketed quanitifier `{2}` will perform more efficiently than the repeated character equivalent.
- Since you are only wanted to replace one at a time, use `1` as the fourth parameter of `preg_replace()` instead of a variable.

Comment: @killer2318 Your question does not appear to be resolved by the SO software.  Does my answer solve your issue or is there still something not quite right.  Confirming the resolution of your issue benefits future SO readers and identifies your question as no longer needing support.